# Laravel - Access forbidden! You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server

Tags: php, laravel

php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Laravel PHP Framework</title>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="welcome">
      <h1>test page</h1>

      <form action="{{ URL::route('dis') }}" method="post">
        First name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
        Last name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <input type="submit">   
      </form>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

display.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>display page</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="welcome">
        <h1>test page for display</h1>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Routes.php

```
<?php
 Route::get('/', array('uses'=>'HomeController@showWelcome', 'as' => 'home'));

 Route::group(array('before'=>'csrf'),function()
 {
     Route::post('/dis', array('uses'=>'HomeController@display', 'as' => 'dis'));
 });
```

HomeController.php

```
<?php

class HomeController extends BaseController {


    public function showWelcome()
    {
        return View::make('hello');
    }

    public function display()
    {
        return View::make('display');
    }

 }
```

there is a error in laravel 5, 
when i try to submit the form hello.html following error appears.

Access forbidden! 
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see is you need a CSRF token in the form. If you also install [illuminate\html](https://github.com/illuminate/html) (which is not included now in Laravel 5) you can get it by using `Form::open` instead of creating the `<form>` tag in HTML as you are.

Alternatively you can add the token to a form by just calling [`csrf_field`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection) function:

```
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```